# AlphaGo Zero board evaluation function uses multiple time steps as an input... Why?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, torch, reinforcement-learning

According to [AlphaGo Cheat Sheet](https://medium.com/applied-data-science/alphago-zero-explained-in-one-diagram-365f5abf67e0), AlphaGo Zero uses a *sequence of consecutive board configurations* to encode its **game state**.

In theory, all the necessary information is contained in the latest state, and yet they include the previous 7 configurations.

Why did they choose to inject so much complexity ?

What are they listening for ??

[AlphaGoZero](https://deepmind.com/blog/alphago-zero-learning-scratch/)

[image: Game State]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sole reason is because in all games - Go, Chess, and Shogi - there is a repetition rule. What this means is that the game is not fully observable from the current board position. In other words, there may be two identical positions with two very different evaluations. For example in one Go position there may be a winning move, but in an identical Go position that move is either illegal or one of the next few moves in the would-be-winning continuation creates an illegal position.

You could try feeding in only the current board position and handling repetitions in the tree only. But I think this would be weaker because the evaluation function would be wrong in some cases, leading to a horizon effect if that branch of the tree had not been explored deeply enough to correct the problem.

Comment: ‘What this means is that the game is not fully observable from the current board position.’  Can you elaborate on this ?   This seems not to be true. Btw thanks for the answer I’m gonna let this question hang out for a bit see what else I can get.

Comment: Imran told the whole story. for go the repetition rule is Ko: https://senseis.xmp.net/?Ko if you see a go game position with a ko you are not able to determine if is legal to take the ko, if you know the last few moves you will be able to do so.
the same goes for the Threefold repetition rule in chess and shogi